# Sorting a vector of pairs that correspond to row and column of matrix

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

I have a matrix of `int`'s. The `<row,col>` pair is stored in an `std::vector`. I would like to sort this `vector` so that after sort, when traversed it gives the elements of the matrix in order. Follows a sample code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int matrix[2][2];
    matrix[0][0] = 4;
    matrix[0][1] = 3;
    matrix[1][0] = 7;
    matrix[1][1] = 6;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pair_indices;
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 0));//Row 0, column 0, corresponds to entry 4
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 1));//Row 0, column 1, corresponds to entry 3
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 0));//Row 1, column 0, corresponds to entry 7
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1));//Row 1, column 1, corresponds to entry 6
    std::sort(pair_indices.begin(), pair_indices.end(), [&](int index_left, int index_right) {
        int i1, j1, i2, j2;
        i1 = pair_indices[index_left].first;
        j1 = pair_indices[index_left].second;
        i2 = pair_indices[index_right].first;
        j2 = pair_indices[index_right].second;
        return matrix[i1][j1] > matrix[i2][j2];//Descending order
    }
    );
    //At this point, I would like pair_indices to be: [ <1,0> | <1,1> | <0,0> | <0,1> ]
    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

The above code doesn't compile with errors in `\include\xutility` and `\include\algorithm`. The error in the source code above is:

```
see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::sort<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,main::<lambda_95ed4bac887c9dd3f80c928a0bd63c0f>>(const _RanIt,const _RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled

with
         [
             _Ty=std::pair<int,int>,
             _RanIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::pair<int,int>>>>,
             _Pr=main::<lambda_95ed4bac887c9dd3f80c928a0bd63c0f>
         ]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to explain how `[ <1,0> | <1,1> | <0,0> | <0,1> ]` is the order of elements in the matrix. I'd rather expect `[ <0,0> | <0,1> | <1,0> | <1,1> ]` and that is what you get from sorting a vector of pairs by default

Comment: oh you want to sort according the the matrix elements value, got it

Comment: I am not sorting the `std::vector` `pairs` in themselves. These are indices into `matrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparator is supposed to take two elements. You are passing a comparator that takes `int`s but the elements of the vector are `std::pair<int,int>`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int matrix[2][2];
    matrix[0][0] = 4;
    matrix[0][1] = 3;
    matrix[1][0] = 7;
    matrix[1][1] = 6;

    using index2d = std::pair<int,int>;

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> pair_indices;
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 0));//Row 0, column 0, corresponds to entry 4
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 1));//Row 0, column 1, corresponds to entry 3
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 0));//Row 1, column 0, corresponds to entry 7
    pair_indices.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 1));//Row 1, column 1, corresponds to entry 6
    std::sort(pair_indices.begin(), 
              pair_indices.end(), 
              [&matrix](const index2d& a,const index2d& b) {         
                    return matrix[a.first][a.second] > matrix[b.first][b.second];//Descending order
              }
    );
    for (const auto& p : pair_indices) {
        std::cout << matrix[p.first][p.second] << '\n';
    }
   // getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
7
6
4
3
```

You don't `#include <utility>` for `std::pair`. The code may compile without it, but you better include what you use. Also I would use `size_t` for the index rather than `int`.

Comment: Ah. I was working with my older code that only had std::vector<int>'s.

Comment: @Tryer passing predicates to algorithms is one corner where error messages are still extremely hard to decipher

Comment: @idclev463035818, true. But, in this case, the words: `reference to function template instantiation with _Ty=std::pair<int,int>` do tell a lot